# ¿Como puedo evitar duplicidad de datos a la hora de llenar un array desde una consulta sql?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql

Quiero traer varios datos según el año al que pertenecen los datos, pero a la hora de hacer un `foreach` me crea mas arreglos con el mismo año, y no unifica los datos por el mismo año:

Consulta a la `base de datos`:

```
   $dataa = DB::table('vista_matriculas_todas')
                 ->select(DB::raw('vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf as anio,meses.id AS MES,SUM(cantidad) as MAT'))
                 ->join('meses', 'meses.id', '=', 'vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte')
                 ->whereIn('vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf',explode(",", $anio))
                 ->whereIn('vista_matriculas_todas.sector',explode(",", $sector))
                 ->whereIn('vista_matriculas_todas.calendario',explode(",", $calendario))
                 ->groupBy('vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf')
                 ->groupBy('meses.id')
                 ->orderBy('vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf','DESC')
                 ->orderBy('meses.id','ASC')
                 ->get();
```

Esto es lo que trae de la `base de datos`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta en la funcion `php`:

```
for ($i=0; $i <=11; $i++) 
{
  $matriculas[$i]=0;
}

foreach ($dataa as $data)
{
  $diasel = intval($data->mes);
  $matriculas[$data->mes-1]=$data->mat;
  $mes = array('anioTtile'=>$data->anio,'anioData'=>$matriculas);
  $datos[] = $mes;
}
return json_encode($datos);
```

Este es el resultado en `consola`:

```
0:{anioTtile: 2018, anioData: ["13", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
1:{anioTtile: 2017, anioData: ["174725", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
2:{anioTtile: 2017, anioData: ["174725", "10344", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Entonces lo que quiero que realmente aparezca es:

```
0:{anioTtile: 2018, anioData: ["13", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
1:{anioTtile: 2017, anioData: ["174725", "10344", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Comment: saludos, haz probado la clausula DISTINCT a tu conulta para ver si lograsel filtrado esperado

Comment: Si claro, sino que realmente este es el resultado de la consulta: 2018  
anio :{2018,2018,2017}, mes :{1,1,1}, mat:{13,174725,10344}

Como tengo varios meses en el mismo año, se duplica

Comment: Hola, por el ejemplo que diste no creo que `distinct` te ayude, si el problema son los ceros repetidos podrías cambiar la linea del select por lo siguiente: `->select(DB::raw('vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf as anio,sum(meses.id) AS MES,SUM(cantidad) as MAT'))` y quita la linea `->groupBy('meses.id')`

Comment: buena propuesta @the-breaker

Comment: Pues lo ceros repetidos son porque los necesito para graficar un chart, de echo los agrego con un for, sino que el tema esta en el foreach, dado a que por un mismo año me esta gerenando varios arreglos y solo necesito uno por año

Comment: No nada que funciona, dado que el problema no esta en la consulta, sino en el foreach

Comment: Creo que con una consulta bastaria, el orm(eloquent) de laravel es super bueno, seria bueno ver tus modelos, estoy seguro que no necesario hacer tanta cosa para obtener el resultado que deseas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agruparlo por años y llenar un array de meses , como el ejemplo a continuacion:

```
for ($i=0; $i <=11; $i++) {
              $matriculas[$i]=0;
    }
    $datos= [];
    foreach ($dataa as $data)  {
        if (!$datos["-".$data->anio]){
           $datos["-".$data->anio] = array("anioTtile" =>$data->anio ,"anioData"  => $matriculas);

         }
         $datos["-".$data->anio]["anioData"][$data->mes-1] = $data->mat;

    }
    return   json_encode($datos);
```

Comment: este es el resultado 'Undefined offset: 2018", exception: "ErrorException' en consola

Comment: ya lo cambie ahora estoy seguro que no tendras problemas , probablemente trabajes con la version 5.3 de PHP

Comment: Nada, que estraño me aparece el mismo error, {message: "Undefined offset: 2018", exception: "ErrorException",…}

Comment: La otra seria nose, validar que el año existe y hacer un push de los datos

Comment: acabo de anteponer un guion prueba nuevamente

Comment: Ups! Nada aparece el mismo error pero ahora con el guion